# Laravel 4 - change order of items

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-4, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two tables `fichas`and `actividads` related in a pivot table called `actividad_ficha`. In this pivot table I've created another column called `orden_actividad`(to short the 'activities' in every 'ficha').

I have a View where I show all the 'activities' related with one specific 'ficha'. I would like to be able to drag-and-drop my list of 'actividads' and save the new order automatically. I'm using some jQuery in my application, but AJAX resists to me.

Do you know how can I get it? or maybe you know some tutorial to bring me some help?

Comment: Have you tried jQuery UI's `sortable`, `draggable` and `droppable`?

Comment: Yes @Kousha. This is exactly what I want!

Comment: Hi @Kousha, could you post the code you told? It would be very helpful!