# AngularJS - $broadcast to only commence on the first match

Tags: angularjs

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child in children">
```

And a directive for `parent`, and one for `child`. The first child gets a flag `scope.isHovered = true`, while everybody else gets a false.

Now, on parent, when a button is clicked, I want the next child to be selected. So what I had was:

```
// Link function of parent
scope.selectNext = function()
{
    scope.$broadcast('HOVER_NEXT');
}

// Link function of child
scope.isHovered = false;
if (scope.$first) scope.isHovered = true;

scope.$on('HOVER_NEXT', function()
{
    if (scope.isHovered && scope.$$nextSibling)
    {
        scope.isHovered = false;  
        scope.$$nextSibling.isHovered = true;
        scope.$apply();
    }
}
```

However, on an event, ALL child get their `isHovered` set to true, since `$on` the broadcast, the first child is called first, and therefore it sets the second child to be true. Then the second child is called, and so on and so forth.

Is there a way to overcome this challenge? Can I call the broadcast on children in reverse order?

Comment: could you answer [this][1], please? Thank you very much!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25020122/laravel-4-change-order-of-items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case of communication between directives - child communicates with parent. Since you did not include your code for directive I will assume simple cases. Thee idea is to not use $broadcast. Avoid $$nextSibling or anything that is $$ - its angular internal and subject to change. The following code snippet captures the gist of what I am saying :-

```
//parent directive
link: function(scope, elm, attr) {
        var currentActive = 1;//first child will be active
        var childCount    = 0;
        $scope.getCurrenActive = function() {
            return currentActive;
        };

        //call this on ng-click of that action you talk about
        $scope.rotateCurrentActive() = function() {
            currentActive++;
            if(angular.isDefined(scope.childCount) 
                && currentActive > childCount) {
                 currentActive=1;
            }
        };

        $scope.register = function() {
            //this serves as a registration number or id to identify the child
            //we can also use this to rotatation back to 1
            return ++childCount;
        }
}


//Child directive
requires: '^parent',
scope: {
     register        : '&'
},
link: function(scope, elm, attr) {
      var myId = scope.register();
      scope.getMyId= function() {
           return myId;
      }
}
```

Now the View/HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child" 
       ng-class="{hover : getMyId() == getCurrentActive()}"></div>
    <div class="child" 
       ng-class="{hover : getMyId() == getCurrentActive()}"></div>
    <div class="child" 
       ng-class="{hover : getMyId() == getCurrentActive()}"></div>
    <div class="child" 
       ng-class="{hover : getMyId() == getCurrentActive()}"></div>
    <div class="child" 
       ng-class="{hover : getMyId() == getCurrentActive()}"></div>
</div>
```